# get all the commits done by me in the last 5 days in git

Tags: git, command-line

I am not very good at sed or awk. Every friday I'd like to see all the commits done by me in the last 5 days, to find out what work I did.

At this time the only command I know of is

```
git log --since=5.days
```

Answer (score 51):

Try `git log --since=5.days --author=roger`, assuming that `roger` is your username.

`--author` actually accepts a regular expression, so if you wanted to find either `roger` or `rachel`'s commits, you could do `git log --since=5.days --author="r(oger|achel)"`.

If you want to search on *any* branch and not just the current one, then also add `--all`.

Comment: Or more generically, `git log --since=5.days --author="$(git config user.name)"` (if you are on your own account). This way you can pass the snippet as-is to your colleagues.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; it only lists commits that happen to be included in the current commit. It does not list commits made in the past five days that are in other branches.

Answer (score 16):

Git supports searching based on the author as well

```
git log --since=5.days --author=Roger
```

Answer (score 5):

To limit commits to yourself, pass the `--author` flag to `git log`, as in `git log --since=5.days --author='Your Name'`.

If you want *less* information than the `git log` default output, you can play around with the formatting options a bit. `git log --since=5.days --oneline` will show you a one-line summary of each commit from the past 5 days (the one-line summary will contain the abbreviated SHA1 hash of the commit as well as the first line of the log message). Or `git log --since=5.days --format=%H` will show *only* the *full* SHA1 hash of the commits from the past 5 days.