# Get all commits pushed to master in the last week using GitHub Workflow

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'd like to create a GitHub Workflow to display all commits pushed to master in the last week (between the current date and the current date minus 7 days).

This is my idea so far:

1. Get the current date: this is easy, and it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942067/get-current-date-and-time-in-github-workflows)
2. Subtract 7 days from the current date: I don't know how to do this yet, in a consistent way.
3. Obtain the list of commits between these two dates: this can easily be done with the `git log` command as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313309/list-git-commits-to-master-branch-between-two-dates), but how can this be converted in the GitHub Workflow Yaml?

Can I have some suggestion on points 2 and 3? or if there is any easier way to achieve what I need, please tell me.

Comment: `git log --since='{7 days ago}'`

Comment: You could easily find https://stackoverflow.com/q/2009577/7976758 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743961/7976758 if you tried to search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+log+days

Comment: Hi @phd thank you for yor comment. As I've said in the question, I'm aware of the git log command, but I don't know how can I use it in the github workflow yaml. Can you post a complete example? thank you!

Comment: My comment and links were about how to calculate "7 days" — put the burden onto Git. In Github Actions you just write the command as in the command line.

Comment: @phd ah this make sense now, thanks. I'll create a test repository to give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for my needs, also thanks to @phd's comment.

I'll write it here, so future users can benefit from it.

First of all, I found a nice app called [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) that allows you to test your github workflow scripts locally (without the need to create a huge amount of commits just to test your script).

The working script is this:

```
name: GH-Workflow-Test

on:
  push:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        fetch-depth: '0'

    - name: Get Weekly Commits
      run: |
        echo 'WEEKLY_COMMITS<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
        git log --format=%B --since=7.days >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Print Commits List
      run: echo ${{ env.WEEKLY_COMMITS }}
```

EDIT: Updated code without the need of the "tr" command. DO NOT forget to set fetch-depth: '0', otherwise you will be able to retrieve only the last commit.